# Why is the delete temp crashing even though the function is defined with new

Tags: c++, gdb, delete-operator

I am making a modified double ended Linked List, but the head and the tail point to each other. In the insertBeforeCurrent and the insertAfterCurrent I defined the objects with new and put them into the Linked List. But when I go to use delete, the program just crashes. I have done some tests, and insertBeforeCurrent and insertAfterCurrent works, and I am able to through the Linked List and print every single element with the getPrevious and getNext. I also printed it using only insertBeforeCurrent, insertAfterCurrent and I was also able to do the same with the mixture of the two. I was able to print it with 1,2,3,and 6 elements in the Linked List. The problem I have is the debugger, everything works until I hit the delete temp; at which point it will just say.
**Can't find a source file at "/build/glibc-t7JzpG/glibc-2.30/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.**
I know you can only use the delete function for delete the data created by the new's dynamic memory allocation, but that doesn't seem to be the case since every element of the Linked List is created by new.

So the issue with application crashing is not the `Node * x = new Node();` followed by `x = y;`. These don't show any warnings,the application runs, and 5 or 6 people have pointed them out. Thank you by the way. My issue is specifically  is the `delete temp;`and why is it not being deleted. I have left the code for some context.

```
EDIT: I have removed the insertBeforeCurrent and insertAfterCurrent code since it is not needed.


 bool CircularDoublyLinkedList::remove(int original_data)
        {
            Node search_data = search(original_data);
            Node* temp = &search_data;
            Node* current_next;
            Node* current_previous;
                if (temp != NULL)
                {
                        if (temp == head)
                        {
                            current_previous = temp->getPrevious();
                            current_next = temp->getNext();
                            current_previous->setNext(current_next);
                            current_next->setPrevious(current_previous);
                            head = current_next;
                            temp->setNext(NULL);
                            temp->setPrevious(NULL);
                            delete temp;
                            current = current_next;
                            cout << "Delete successful." << endl;
                        }
                        else if (temp == tail)
                        {
                            current_previous = temp->getPrevious();
                            current_next = temp->getNext();
                            current_next->setPrevious(current_previous);
                            current_previous->setNext(current_next);
                            tail = current_next;
                            temp->setNext(NULL);
                            temp->setPrevious(NULL);
                            delete temp;
                            current = current_next;
                            cout << "Delete successful." << endl;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            current_previous = temp->getPrevious();
                            current_next = temp->getNext();
                            current_previous->setNext(current_next);
                            current_next->setPrevious(current_previous);
                            temp->setNext(NULL);
                            temp->setPrevious(NULL);
                            delete temp;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
```

Comment: The function does not make sense. For example in thois code snippet         current = new Node();
        head = new Node();
        head->setData(inserted_data);
        tail = head;
        current = head; there is a memory leak.

Comment: Also `Node* temp = new Node();
            if (temp == head)` is _never_ going to be true. As well as `else if (temp == tail)`. You will always hit the `else` there.

Comment: `current = new Node();` followed by `current = head;`. Think about that for a moment.

Comment: Not a [mcve].  [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) may be helpful, all C++ programmers should be able to use a debugger.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `windows` and `linux-kernel`? Pick one. Or better, none, as this does not seem to be related to either tags.

Comment: Also note, that a pointer doesn't need to be initialized with a `new`. `Node* current_next = new Node();
        Node* current_previous = new Node();
        Node* temp = new Node();` are threee memory leaks. `Node* current_next;` is a perfectly valid way to declare a variable that you are going to overwrite anyway before reading.

Comment: I think you don't understand pointers and dynamic memory allocation, which is a problem if you're writing code like this. Look at your `remove` function for instance, why is it allocating new nodes? If you are removing a node from a linked list you need to delete a node, you don't need to create any new ones. That's just common sense. As you can see from the comments above there are multiple issues with this code.

Comment: Take a close look at what you are  attempting to `delete`. After `Node search_data = search(original_data);
Node* temp = &search_data;` `temp ` is pointing to a local variable, i.e. you try to delete stack memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know you can only use the delete function for delete the data created by the new's dynamic memory allocation,

So far so good.

> but that doesn't seem to be the case since every element of the Linked List is created by new.

This is not relevant, since the `temp` in `CircularDoublyLinkedList::remove()` never points to an element of the linked list. You assign to `temp` the address of a local variable (`search_data`) and never change that. Local variables are not created by `new`, so  (as you noted earlier), you cannot `delete &search_data`.

*(You might have noticed this yourself had you used a debugger to step through your code while trying to delete the first element of the list. In your current code, `temp == head` will never be true, even though that is the branch for deleting the first element. Similarly, `temp == tail` will never be true, and `temp != NULL` will never be false.)*

At a guess, your `search()` function should probably return a pointer to a node in the list instead of returning the node, at which point you'll no longer need the (poorly-named) `temp` variable.

Comment: Yup I did that, @churill pointed that out in the comments. I was going to check if &search_data  but you have said it is false. I have created the `Node* search(int Data, char a)` to fix it.